# How to read image from StringIO into PIL in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How to read image from StringIO into PIL in python?  I will have a stringIO object.  How to I read from it with a image in it? I cant event have ot read a image from a file.  Wow!

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image

image_file = StringIO(open("test.gif",'rb').readlines())
im = Image.open(image_file)
print im.format, "%dx%d" % im.size, im.mode

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/receipt/imap_poller.py", line 22, in <module>
    im = Image.open(image_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pillow-2.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 2028, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

Comment: I don't think StringIO is actually necessary here - just use `im = Image.open("test.gif")`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use [`readlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.readlines), it returns a list of strings which is not what you want. To retrieve the bytes from the file, use [`read()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.read) function instead.

Your example worked out of the box with `read()` and a `JPG` file on my PC:

```
# Python 2.x
>>>from StringIO import StringIO
# Python 3.x
>>>from io import StringIO

>>>from PIL import Image

>>>image_file = StringIO(open("test.jpg",'rb').read())
>>>im = Image.open(image_file)
>>>print im.size, im.mode
(2121, 3508) RGB
```

Comment: It may be a version change, but this doesn't work now: 
    $ python Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276, Oct 5 2020, 11:29:23) [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin 
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
    >>> from io import StringIO 
    >>> from PIL import Image 
    >>> image_file = StringIO(open("t.jpg",'rb').read()) 
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
    TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: I found using io.BytesIO() instead of io.StringIO works